# 8258 Headlight assemblies

Tags: technic, instructions

Anyone else having a problem with with headlight assemblies on 8258 crane truck?  I can't seem to fit them in due to interference from fog light bar. Thanks

[image: Step 110 from instruction book 3]

Comment: I never noticed any problem with it. Do you have a picture of your model.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the picture, it appears as if there is a brick (a 1x2 brick, light gray) behind the headlight. The headlight connects to it in a similar fashion as shown in the following image:

[image]

Hopefully that helps.